# reactJS disable console.log system wide

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have console.log all over the place. Removing them all is not good as I might need them again. Is there way I can do something like this for entire react app?

```
if(env === 'production'){
  console.log= function(){}
}
```

Comment: There's a way to overload the function like you're trying to do here. However, I would just do a folder search on my project and search-replace all instances of `console.log(` with `//console.log(`.

Comment: What about the opposite: I have a bunch of console.log statements that won't show, but I want them to show!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given you are using React, it is likely that you are already using babel as a part of your build process.

You can use this [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-remove-console/) to remove all the console.* function invocations in the build phase.

Comment: Please don't use this. All you're doing is making it more difficult for anyone who needs console.log access on your website. Use a custom logger then find/replace all instances of console.log.

Comment: @AndrewFenn Genuine question, why would somebody ever need console.log access on my website? Are there legitimate, non-malicious use cases I should be concerned about breaking if I block console.log?

Answer (score 26):

In your `index.js` file, check if you're running in dev or production mode.

Disable console.log if you're in production mode.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development")
    console.log = () => {};
```

Answer (score 5):

A much safer way is to not use `console.log` and go with a custom logger implementation that you can turn off when needed.

To get you going with something, you can use the excellent [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) npm package that makes it easy to turn off globally or selectively and it works on both nodejs server side and client side.

Answer (score 5):

In your index.js file you can simply replace console.log method with an empty function that does nothing. In Node or Frontend app, this should be placed in the file where the application starts from.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log = () => {}
  console.error = () => {}
  console.debug = () => {}
}
```

Now throughout the application in production environment console.log() calls will print nothing. For all other environments, the usual console.log will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function consoleLog() {
  const args = [...arguments];
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    console.log(args[i]);
  }
}
```

save this is a file somewhere, then search all of your files for console.log and replace with consoleLog and make sure you import it at the top of each file where you want to use it.

When you build your production bundle you can simply change it to...

```
export function consoleLog() {
  // const args = [...arguments];
  // for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
  //  console.log(args[i]);
  // }
}
```

Comment: Simple and practical. I would use a variable instead of commenting out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== "development") {
    var console = {};
    console.log = function () {};
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Comment: The variable is called `NODE_ENV`, not `ENVIRONMENT`.

Comment: Looking at this again, the problems go beyond that: a) Why use `var` when you can just assign to `console`? b) If there are any other `console` methods called in the application, they will throw an Error when called because of null references.