# Turning off debug statements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to include a function to console debug statements in React that would be empty when the app is built for production. I don't want to precede the `console.log()` statement by an `if` statement and leave it in there because... well it just doesn't make sense to me! Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I need to indicate that I'm using `create-react-app` and would not like to eject please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactJS disable console.log system wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708586/reactjs-disable-console-log-system-wide)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the babel plugin with `create-react-app` without ejecting.

Comment: You can do it with https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired and `injectBabelPlugin`